# Подмножества множества

Tags: c, алгоритм

Есть целый массив длины n, содержащий n различных значений (массив множество). Программа должна печатать все подмножества данного множества. К примеру есть массив [1,2,3], решением для него будет {1} {2} {3} {1,2} {1,3} {1,2,3}. Есть идея обозначать вхождение через 1, а не вхождение через 0. Но дальше не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ - основанный на вашей идее :) - перебор всех чисел от 0 до 2<sup>n</sup>, и выбор элементов множества в соответствии с единицами в бинарном представлении:

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };


int main()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (1 << sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])); ++i)
    {
        unsigned int n = i, j = 0;
        while(n)
        {
            if (n&1) printf("%d  ",a[j]);
            ++j;
            n >>= 1;
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще есть стандартные алгоритмы permutation & combination.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination (см. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations_for_all_k). И этот как раз показывает решение "в лоб".

Comment: @0andriy В данном случае это генерация всех кортежей, а не сочетаний или перестановок.

Comment: Вы по сслыке почитайте, да? ;)

Comment: @0andriy Ну что вы, чукча не читатель, чукча писатель...